# Why is your taste affected due to sinuses?

Tags: taste, sensory-systems

I heard someone say "My sinuses are acting up, I can't taste the food." I don't think the person is lying, they probably believe this but I'm having trouble seeing how the sinuses would affect the taste buds. I realize smell helps identify foods, but it seems like not smelling a food wouldn't affect taste so severely as people make it sound.

I don't have sinus troubles much and haven't experienced this, so I'm not claiming it's fake, I'm just curious to understand how that works.

Comment: Scent and taste are intimately connected. Try tasting something flavorful, rinsing your mouth out with water, then holding your nose and tasting it again - it will be much "duller". Taste buds and scent receptors signal to the same part of the brain.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing which is important to note is the difference between *taste* and *flavor*.
**Taste** refers to the chemical sense performed by taste buds present on the tongue, and to date there have been identified 5 tastes: sweet, bitter, sour, salty and umami. Thus I understand obstructed nose and sinuses should have no significant effect on taste.
**Flavor**, on the other hand, is the final sensation that conveys the information about the food we're eating, and involves not only **taste**, but also **smell**, **mechanical sensation** (like that smooth flavor from cream) and **pain and temperature** pathways (hot and spicy food, like peppers). Part of the signals from all these receptors located on the mouth (and nasal) cavity ultimately converge to the same location in the brain, where they are processed to create the final flavor (I know taste and smell do converge to the same region, cannot tell the others with full certainty).
So, having obstructed sinuses and nasal cavity can interfere with the smell detection (by not allowing molecules to bind to receptors on the olfactory epithelium), and thus interfere with flavor.

You can check this site which I think explains very well what I am trying to pass on, it is very clear and covers all the physiology that I talked about, allowing you to go deeper into details if you are interested: http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/biosi/staffinfo/jacob/teaching/sensory/taste.html and also http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/biosi/staffinfo/jacob/teaching/sensory/olfact1.html (you have to scroll down to the main text)

Comment: any sources to add?

Comment: @AliceD I wrote based on what I have been studying over time, from neuroanatomy and anatomy to physiology, and also some autonomous research, but if you search it on google you will probably get the same information, maybe even in Wikipedia!

Comment: @Filipe I suggest you search through those sites (and preferably more reputable sites as well) and add some sources to your answer. Otherwise, it will be closed/deleted. See [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for a guide to writing good answers on Bio.SE.Thanks

Comment: @theforestecologist i feel as if we are giving way to much importance to reputation. I am simply sharing part of the knowledge I have been accumulating over time, from what I have studied in Medical school to what I have read in my personal researches and life experience. That is how it should be taken, as me trying to share what I know with another person, and not the whole and absolute truth - and that's science, in my opinion. I don't think reputation should be so impactful, but rather the facts that are behind what I'm saying.

Comment: @FilipeRocha - everyone can claim to be an expert and start babbling away. Although I don't doubt your expertise in this area I'm downvoting your answer as you're blandly ignoring the advice of hi-rep users. Please understand - reputation on this site is a reflection of nothing more than user effort; even laymen can gain a lot of rep here simply by quoting wikipedia. The reason we ask for sources is that it allows users to background read on the topic and get in-depth understanding of your answer.

Comment: @Filipe and all that experience makes finding proper sources easier because you already know some sources, you know the proper keywords to find new ones and you can better recognize their validity. Anecdotal information is interesting for sure, but on this site we require that you back up your answers with sources b/c other users don't have the experience to know what is valid or not. If you want to share anecdotal info/answeres on Bio.SE, it is best shared (and welcomed) in the comments.

Comment: @theforestecologist thank you for the explanation, it does make sense and if it was me I would also like others to show me where can I find something that I can use to verify or further learn about the topic.  So I went looking for such and found this site which I think explains very well what I was trying to pass on, it is very clear and covers all that I talked about: http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/biosi/staffinfo/jacob/teaching/sensory/taste.html

I hope you find it useful (you have to scroll down to the main text), and once again thank you

Comment: @AliceD the answer above is also for you :)

Comment: @Filipe Great! Just one last thing: we ask that answers be complete (i.e., not needing comments to "fill-in" further information). Please incorporate your link *into* your answer. Further, providing *context* for the link is super useful because some links break over time; as a result, it's useful to provide a bit more than just the link (.e.g, what does the link contain, what part of your answer is it pertinent to, etc.). Copying (and citing) a photo (which that site has numerous) would be a great addition to your answer as well :). Thanks for putting in the effort to improve!

Comment: @theforestecologist done :)